# Script/Command for compiling and running a single C file in single step?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I want to run single C files with a single command, just like we can run any python file `example.py` with the command-

```
python example.py
```

I cannot find any GCC or Make command or even any script (in linux) to do this. I want to run any C file `example.c` with the some command like-

```
crun example.c
```

and then the single C file will compile and run. I don't bother if some other files are created in the process. Is there any command or script for this?

Comment: You could just write one to do that. It would probably take 2 lines.

Comment: It works for python because it's an interpreter, not a compiler. There's no C interpreter on Linux.

Comment: I am not enough proficient, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#!/bin/sh
OUT="$(mktemp)"
rm $OUT
gcc -o $OUT $1 && ( shift ; $OUT $* )
rm -f $OUT
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your first `rm $OUT`? it will very likely raise an error. Why do you run the compiled program in a subshell? why do you use `$*` and not `"$@"`? Why don't you use more quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a c language interpreter.
Like cint(CINT is an interpreter for C and C++ code.):
https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint

This c interpreter (https://github.com/kazuho/C) is also good.
You can do things like this:

```
root@foo ~:c -e 'printf("hello")'
root@foo ~:hello
```

Or for something like ipython you can try this:

http://da.vidr.cc/projects/iccsh/

Comment: Actually I am trying to run full c files, not line by line code interpretation. Thanks anyway.